# Scala, math with template typed parameters

Tags: scala, templates

I am trying to create a generic class in Scala that takes numeric types that inside the class math will be done.  The goal is to use different math types as the template arguments.
How can I get this to work:

```
def plus[T <: AnyVal](v1: T <:< AnyVal, v2: T <:< AnyVal): T = {
    v1 + v2
}

so that I can do this:
val t1 = 4, t2 = 5
val t3 = plus(t1, t2)
or
val t3: Int = plus[Int](t1, t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to use typeclasses. See [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire). Actually, no wait, just use Spire. It's really quite incredible and optimized to avoid boxing as much as possible.

If you don't want to use Spire, here is an example of what I mean by typeclass:

```
trait Add[A]
  def apply(x: A, y: A): A
}

def plus[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit add: Add[A]) = add(x, y)
```

And you'll have to define the type class for every type you wish to support.